# Need to use a variable in a different class

Tags: python

In first class I have a function which adds numbers and returns the result. I have a score in field result. I need make this field in next class (other file) in function, which will add me a number to `result`.

```
def addFunction(self):
    result = a+b


def addGroup(self):
    score = 95 + 'result'
```

Comment: So if there are two calsses/Scripts - where do you call the other one (methodB - `addGroup`)? If they are running all the time you just need to `import <yout class>.<variable>` and then you can use it.

Comment: Please format your code with proper format. Also your functions aren't returning anything....

Comment: @MooingRawr I mean, that's what the edit button *for you* is for, to help new users understand how to do so.

Comment: Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime. @Drise Part of programming is learning to research yourself and read documents. There are plenty of resources telling you how to format code, even on the `ask a question` page it tells you `► indent code by 4 spaces`